# Can't figure out how to play steaming video from a url with MoboPlayer

Tags: video

How can a video player like [MoBo Player](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.clov4r.android.nil&hl=en) play content from a URL?

I am not seeing any option after installing the app. Also, the search icon does nothing.

Answer (score 1):

### Four steps:

1. Open the [MoboPlayer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.clov4r.android.nil&hl=en) app;
2. If you don't see a small menu with icons at the bottom of your screen, tap "home" to bring that up, then tap "...";
3. From the white extra options board, scroll to see the far right side. There you will find "Streaming", tap to access;
4. Enter URL and enjoy the show.

[image: MoboPlayer Screen Shot]